# Как к элементу добавить +1 при нажатии?

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно сделать так, что нажатые элемент является li, то тогда к его значению нужно прибавить +1.
У меня прибавляется число 2 к каждой li при нажатии почему-то

```js
let ul = document.querySelector('ul');
ul.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
   if (event.target.tagName == 'LI') {
      let number = 1;
      number++;
      event.target.innerHTML += number;
   }
})
```

```html
 <ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
let ul = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
ul.forEach(li=>li.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      let number = +event.target.textContent;
      number++;
      event.target.textContent = number;
   }
));
```

```html
<ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

Код вполне рабочий даже без промежуточной переменной:

```js
let ul = document.querySelector('ul');
ul.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  if (ev.target.tagName != 'LI') return;
  ev.target.innerHTML = ++ev.target.textContent;
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```